# Mapping basic typedef aliases with ctypes?

Tags: python, c, typedef, ctypes

I understand how to define structs in Python with ctypes, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to handle basic aliases. For example [64-bit integers in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/int64.html):

```
#ifdef SQLITE_INT64_TYPE
  typedef SQLITE_INT64_TYPE sqlite_int64;
  typedef unsigned SQLITE_INT64_TYPE sqlite_uint64;
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)
  typedef __int64 sqlite_int64;
  typedef unsigned __int64 sqlite_uint64;
#else
  typedef long long int sqlite_int64;
  typedef unsigned long long int sqlite_uint64;
#endif
typedef sqlite_int64 sqlite3_int64;
typedef sqlite_uint64 sqlite3_uint64;
```

Depending on the build options, the basic type is different. In this case, I think I can make an assumption that the type is `c_longlong`, but is that the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this certainly isn't the 'correct' way to handle this, short of using the C API instead of `ctypes`, this is the only solution. By the time `ctypes` runs, the typedef information has been removed - it doesn't appear as symbols in the compiled library.

Comment: By "using the C API instead of ctypes," you mean actually calling the original C library from some other C code that exposes functions via the Python C API?

Comment: Ivc means writing the code as a C extension for Python, which, assuming SQLite was built on the same machine you build the C extension on, would allow you to do the same preprocessor conditional checks done in the SQLite code. (http://docs.python.org/extending/index.html or http://docs.python.org/py3k/extending/index.html, or somewhere around there, depending on what version of Python you're using.)